# Issues in downloading android sdk source code

Tags: android, git, ubuntu-10.04, android-source

I am trying to download the android sdk source.

Following are the steps I did for the same.

```
curl http://android.git.kernel.org/repo >~/bin/repo
chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
PATH=$PATH:~/bin
export PATH
mkdir mydroid
cd mydroid
repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git -b froyo
```

I get the following message returned to me after I issues the repo init command in terminal -- "revision froyo in manifests not found"

I have been pulling out my hairs trying to find a solution for the  same. Experts , kindly help.

I am doing this from Ubuntu environment.

Experts please help with a solution.

Looking forward,
Best Regards,
Anees

Edit: I tired for master branch also and I got

```
anees@Anees-desktop:~/mydroid1$ repo init -u

git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git

 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/anees/mydroid1/.repo/repo/main.py", line 238, in <module>
_Main(sys.argv[1:])
File "/home/anees/mydroid1/.repo/repo/main.py", line 220, in _Main
repo._Run(argv)
File "/home/anees/mydroid1/.repo/repo/main.py", line 125, in _Run
cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
 File "/home/anees/mydroid1/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 231, in Execute
self._SyncManifest(opt)
 File "/home/anees/mydroid1/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 119, in _SyncManifest
 m.PreSync()
 File "/home/anees/mydroid1/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1594, in PreSync
cb = self.CurrentBranch
 File "/home/anees/mydroid1/.repo/repo/project.py", line 277, in CurrentBranch
b = self.work_git.GetHead()
 File "/home/anees/mydroid1/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1380, in GetHead
 fd = open(path, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:    '/home/anees/mydroid1/.repo/manifests/.git/HEAD'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this problem a few times but it is usually mainly caused by the fact that someone tried to do "repo init" in the same directory twice (or something failed during initialization). 
So if you get something along the lines of (Python error):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/developer/android_src/.repo/repo/main.py", line 238, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/developer/android_src/.repo/repo/main.py", line 220, in _Main
    repo._Run(argv)
  File "/home/developer/android_src/.repo/repo/main.py", line 125, in _Run
    cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "/home/developer/android_src/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 231, in Execute
    self._SyncManifest(opt)
  File "/home/developer/android_src/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 143, in _SyncManifest
    m.Sync_LocalHalf(syncbuf)
  File "/home/developer/android_src/.repo/repo/project.py", line 688, in Sync_LocalHalf
    head = self.work_git.GetHead()
  File "/home/developer/android_src/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1380, in GetHead
    fd = open(path, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/developer/android_src/.repo/manifests/.git/HEAD'
```

then try to run the same command in the new directory. That is why the error is showing on master branch for the original user (Go make a new dir and try to get master branch).

But initial question was why it fails is due to option "-b froyo".  The "froyo" branch/tag does not seem to exist at the moment.  Try one of the following instead :

```
From git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest
 * [new branch]      android-1.5 -> origin/android-1.5
 * [new branch]      android-1.5r2 -> origin/android-1.5r2
 * [new branch]      android-1.5r3 -> origin/android-1.5r3
 * [new branch]      android-1.5r4 -> origin/android-1.5r4
 * [new branch]      android-1.6_r1 -> origin/android-1.6_r1
 * [new branch]      android-1.6_r1.1 -> origin/android-1.6_r1.1
 * [new branch]      android-1.6_r1.2 -> origin/android-1.6_r1.2
 * [new branch]      android-1.6_r1.3 -> origin/android-1.6_r1.3
 * [new branch]      android-1.6_r1.4 -> origin/android-1.6_r1.4
 * [new branch]      android-1.6_r1.5 -> origin/android-1.6_r1.5
 * [new branch]      android-1.6_r2 -> origin/android-1.6_r2
 * [new branch]      android-2.0.1_r1 -> origin/android-2.0.1_r1
 * [new branch]      android-2.0_r1 -> origin/android-2.0_r1
 * [new branch]      android-2.1_r1 -> origin/android-2.1_r1
 * [new branch]      android-2.1_r2 -> origin/android-2.1_r2
 * [new branch]      android-2.1_r2.1p -> origin/android-2.1_r2.1p
 * [new branch]      android-2.1_r2.1p2 -> origin/android-2.1_r2.1p2
 * [new branch]      android-2.1_r2.1s -> origin/android-2.1_r2.1s
 * [new branch]      android-2.2.1_r1 -> origin/android-2.2.1_r1
 * [new branch]      android-2.2.1_r2 -> origin/android-2.2.1_r2
 * [new branch]      android-2.2.2_r1 -> origin/android-2.2.2_r1
 * [new branch]      android-2.2_r1 -> origin/android-2.2_r1
 * [new branch]      android-2.2_r1.1 -> origin/android-2.2_r1.1
 * [new branch]      android-2.2_r1.2 -> origin/android-2.2_r1.2
 * [new branch]      android-2.2_r1.3 -> origin/android-2.2_r1.3
 * [new branch]      android-2.3.1_r1 -> origin/android-2.3.1_r1
 * [new branch]      android-2.3.2_r1 -> origin/android-2.3.2_r1
 * [new branch]      android-2.3_r1 -> origin/android-2.3_r1
 * [new branch]      android-adt-0.9.8 -> origin/android-adt-0.9.8
 * [new branch]      android-adt-0.9.9 -> origin/android-adt-0.9.9
 * [new branch]      android-cts-2.1_r2 -> origin/android-cts-2.1_r2
 * [new branch]      android-cts-2.1_r3 -> origin/android-cts-2.1_r3
 * [new branch]      android-cts-2.1_r4 -> origin/android-cts-2.1_r4
 * [new branch]      android-cts-2.1_r5 -> origin/android-cts-2.1_r5
 * [new branch]      android-cts-2.2_r1 -> origin/android-cts-2.2_r1
 * [new branch]      android-cts-2.2_r2 -> origin/android-cts-2.2_r2
 * [new branch]      android-cts-2.2_r3 -> origin/android-cts-2.2_r3
 * [new branch]      android-cts-2.2_r4 -> origin/android-cts-2.2_r4
 * [new branch]      android-cts-2.3_r1 -> origin/android-cts-2.3_r1
 * [new branch]      android-sdk-1.5-pre -> origin/android-sdk-1.5-pre
 * [new branch]      android-sdk-1.5_r1 -> origin/android-sdk-1.5_r1
 * [new branch]      android-sdk-1.5_r3 -> origin/android-sdk-1.5_r3
 * [new branch]      android-sdk-1.6-docs_r1 -> origin/android-sdk-1.6-docs_r1
 * [new branch]      android-sdk-1.6_r1 -> origin/android-sdk-1.6_r1
 * [new branch]      android-sdk-1.6_r2 -> origin/android-sdk-1.6_r2
 * [new branch]      android-sdk-2.0.1-docs_r1 -> origin/android-sdk-2.0.1-docs_r1
 * [new branch]      android-sdk-2.0.1_r1 -> origin/android-sdk-2.0.1_r1
 * [new branch]      android-sdk-2.0_r1 -> origin/android-sdk-2.0_r1
 * [new branch]      android-sdk-2.1_r1 -> origin/android-sdk-2.1_r1
 * [new branch]      android-sdk-2.2_r1 -> origin/android-sdk-2.2_r1
 * [new branch]      android-sdk-2.2_r2 -> origin/android-sdk-2.2_r2
 * [new branch]      android-sdk-tools_r2 -> origin/android-sdk-tools_r2
 * [new branch]      android-sdk-tools_r3 -> origin/android-sdk-tools_r3
 * [new branch]      android-sdk-tools_r4 -> origin/android-sdk-tools_r4
 * [new branch]      android-sdk-tools_r5 -> origin/android-sdk-tools_r5
 * [new branch]      android-sdk-tools_r6 -> origin/android-sdk-tools_r6
 * [new branch]      android-sdk-tools_r7 -> origin/android-sdk-tools_r7
 * [new branch]      cdma-import -> origin/cdma-import
 * [new branch]      cupcake    -> origin/cupcake
 * [new branch]      cupcake-release -> origin/cupcake-release
 * [new branch]      donut      -> origin/donut
 * [new branch]      donut-plus-aosp -> origin/donut-plus-aosp
 * [new branch]      eclair     -> origin/eclair
 * [new branch]      froyo-plus-aosp -> origin/froyo-plus-aosp
 * [new branch]      gingerbread -> origin/gingerbread
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      release-1.0 -> origin/release-1.0
 * [new branch]      tools_r7   -> origin/tools_r7
 * [new branch]      tools_r8   -> origin/tools_r8
 * [new branch]      tools_r9   -> origin/tools_r9
 * [new tag]         android-1.5 -> android-1.5
 * [new tag]         android-1.5r2 -> android-1.5r2
 * [new tag]         android-1.5r3 -> android-1.5r3
 * [new tag]         android-1.5r4 -> android-1.5r4
 * [new tag]         android-1.6_r1 -> android-1.6_r1
 * [new tag]         android-1.6_r1.1 -> android-1.6_r1.1
 * [new tag]         android-1.6_r1.2 -> android-1.6_r1.2
 * [new tag]         android-1.6_r1.3 -> android-1.6_r1.3
 * [new tag]         android-1.6_r1.4 -> android-1.6_r1.4
 * [new tag]         android-1.6_r1.5 -> android-1.6_r1.5
 * [new tag]         android-1.6_r2 -> android-1.6_r2
 * [new tag]         android-2.0.1_r1 -> android-2.0.1_r1
 * [new tag]         android-2.0_r1 -> android-2.0_r1
 * [new tag]         android-2.1_r1 -> android-2.1_r1
 * [new tag]         android-2.1_r2 -> android-2.1_r2
 * [new tag]         android-2.1_r2.1p -> android-2.1_r2.1p
 * [new tag]         android-2.1_r2.1p2 -> android-2.1_r2.1p2
 * [new tag]         android-2.1_r2.1s -> android-2.1_r2.1s
 * [new tag]         android-2.2.1_r1 -> android-2.2.1_r1
 * [new tag]         android-2.2.1_r2 -> android-2.2.1_r2
 * [new tag]         android-2.2.2_r1 -> android-2.2.2_r1
 * [new tag]         android-2.2_r1 -> android-2.2_r1
 * [new tag]         android-2.2_r1.1 -> android-2.2_r1.1
 * [new tag]         android-2.2_r1.2 -> android-2.2_r1.2
 * [new tag]         android-2.2_r1.3 -> android-2.2_r1.3
 * [new tag]         android-2.3.1_r1 -> android-2.3.1_r1
 * [new tag]         android-2.3.2_r1 -> android-2.3.2_r1
 * [new tag]         android-2.3_r1 -> android-2.3_r1
 * [new tag]         android-adt-0.9.8 -> android-adt-0.9.8
 * [new tag]         android-adt-0.9.9 -> android-adt-0.9.9
 * [new tag]         android-cts-2.1_r2 -> android-cts-2.1_r2
 * [new tag]         android-cts-2.1_r3 -> android-cts-2.1_r3
 * [new tag]         android-cts-2.1_r4 -> android-cts-2.1_r4
 * [new tag]         android-cts-2.1_r5 -> android-cts-2.1_r5
 * [new tag]         android-cts-2.2_r1 -> android-cts-2.2_r1
 * [new tag]         android-cts-2.2_r2 -> android-cts-2.2_r2
 * [new tag]         android-cts-2.2_r3 -> android-cts-2.2_r3
 * [new tag]         android-cts-2.2_r4 -> android-cts-2.2_r4
 * [new tag]         android-cts-2.3_r1 -> android-cts-2.3_r1
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-1.5-pre -> android-sdk-1.5-pre
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-1.5_r1 -> android-sdk-1.5_r1
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-1.5_r3 -> android-sdk-1.5_r3
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-1.6-docs_r1 -> android-sdk-1.6-docs_r1
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-1.6_r1 -> android-sdk-1.6_r1
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-1.6_r2 -> android-sdk-1.6_r2
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-2.0.1-docs_r1 -> android-sdk-2.0.1-docs_r1
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-2.0.1_r1 -> android-sdk-2.0.1_r1
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-2.0_r1 -> android-sdk-2.0_r1
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-2.1_r1 -> android-sdk-2.1_r1
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-2.2_r1 -> android-sdk-2.2_r1
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-2.2_r2 -> android-sdk-2.2_r2
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-tools_r2 -> android-sdk-tools_r2
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-tools_r3 -> android-sdk-tools_r3
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-tools_r4 -> android-sdk-tools_r4
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-tools_r5 -> android-sdk-tools_r5
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-tools_r6 -> android-sdk-tools_r6
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-tools_r7 -> android-sdk-tools_r7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting master branch by removing `-b froyo`:

```
repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Like SillentTroll suggests, you probably need to install more software on your system.  These are most of the tools you will need:

> sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential
>   zip curl zlib1g-dev libc6-dev lib32ncurses5-dev ia32-libs
>   x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32readline5-dev lib32z-dev
>   libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 tofrodos python-markdown
>   libxml2-utils xsltproc

I found this tutorial very helpful:  [Compile ICS Tutorial](http://forums.androidcentral.com/hacking/144804-how-compile-ics-aosp-4-0-3-xoom-gnex-nexus-s.html)

Answer (score -1):

if you get "No such file or directory" , then try to install "git-core". 
It worked for me.